# Loading parquet files from a partitioned S3 path efficiently using Spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to load data from the S3 path `s3://my-bucket/data-set-name/`, which has several partitions like below:

```
s3://my-bucket/data-set-name/region_id=1/market_id=1/dataset_day=2023-03-11/
s3://my-bucket/data-set-name/region_id=1/market_id=1/dataset_day=2023-03-10/
(more files for region_id=1; market_id=X; and dataset_day=YYYY-MM-DD)
s3://my-bucket/data-set-name/region_id=2/market_id=1/dataset_day=2023-03-11/
s3://my-bucket/data-set-name/region_id=2/market_id=1/dataset_day=2023-03-10/
(more files for region_id=2; market_id=X; and dataset_day=YYYY-MM-DD)
s3://my-bucket/data-set-name/region_id=3/market_id=1/dataset_day=2023-03-11/
s3://my-bucket/data-set-name/region_id=3/market_id=1/dataset_day=2023-03-10/
(more files for region_id=X; market_id=X; and dataset_day=YYYY-MM-DD)
```

In each of the S3 path above, there are a little over 1000 parquet files each of which is about ~350MB in size.

Right now, the existing code is reading the data as follows:

```
val s3Bucket = "s3://my-bucket/data-set-name/"
val df: DataFrame = spark.table(s3Bucket).filter(
  col("region_id").isin(regionIds:_*) && // here, regionIds is something like [1,2,3]
  col("market_id").isin(marketIds:_*) && // same as above, marketIds is something like [1,2,3,111,222,...]
  col("dataset_day").isin(datasetDays:_*) // datasetDays is, in fact, a range of dates starting from a start date to an end date; for example, it is a list containing all the dates from Jan 1, 2023 to Mar 15, 2023 like ["2023-01-01", "2023-01-02", ...., "2023-03-15"]
).as(gdp2Alias)
```

Q1: Is there a more efficient way to read the data from S3 because as a beginner learning Spark, I feel like `spark.table(s3Bucket)` would read ALL of the data and THEN we filter by `region_id`, `market_id` and `dataset_day` on that data? Or is Spark smart enough to read just the ones that matches the `filter` conditions in the code above (that is, there's not much to optimize in terms of reading data here)?

Q2: In my beginner's eyes, `isin(datasetDays:_*)` should be less efficient than something like `.filter(col("dataset_day") <= max_date_from_datasetDays && col("dataset_day") >= min_date_from_datasetDays)`? Is that assumption correct?

Thank you in advance for your answers!

Comment: What backend you are using? eg: glue/databricks?

Comment: @Yefet - I am using EMR cluster on AWS. Not sure if that answers your question. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at predicate push down with partition pruning.

https://towardsdatascience.com/predicate-vs-projection-pushdown-in-spark-3-ac24c4d11855

How much data and/or files are skipped depends on the granularity of partitions.  This answers Q1.  Unfortunately, it sounds like you have 1000 files x 350 MB per file for each partition.  Add more filtering if possible to reduce the number of files read.

Make sure settings are enabled.

```
"spark.sql.parquet.filterPushdown", "true"
"spark.hadoop.parquet.filter.stats.enabled", "true"
"spark.sql.optimizer.nestedSchemaPruning.enabled","true"
"spark.sql.optimizer.dynamicPartitionPruning.enabled", "true"
```

Look at the execution plan - explain().  This will help you answer Q2.

Comment: Thank you. I am using Spark 2.2 and filter settings above are enabled in my Spark environment. Based on your answer, as long as I use `spark.table(...).filter(....)` or `spark.read.parquet(...).filter(...)` and these filter settings enabled, Spark should intelligently read just the relevant partitions?